# ISAPI filter and compression cancellation

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, isapi

I have an old style ISAPI filter which intercepts SF_NOTIFY_SEND_RESPONSE and changes the Content-Type to */* and sets Content-Encoding to empty string. It happens when the response body is smaller than some threshold and its done for compression cancelation. So far it works but I have two concerns.

1. Is this the right way to do what I've done from technical point of view?
2. Could Content-Type altering be potentially dangerous?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like setting Content-Encoding to empty string is enough, this way you dont have to deal with mime-type changes which can be potentially dangerous